# Python requests library in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-glue

Can you use the Python's request library in AWS Glue? Is there a replacement to the  Requests library that can be used with Glue since Glue only supports pure python modules?

Comment: This seems to work in AWS Glue Python3 scripts now. I believe `requests` had been added recently, but wasn't able to verify with any official source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [*urllib*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) package.

From the Documentation:

> urllib is a package that collects several modules for working with
>   URLs:
>
> - urllib.request for opening and reading URLs
> - urllib.error containing    the exceptions raised by urllib.request
> - urllib.parse for parsing URLs
> - urllib.robotparser for parsing robots.txt files

A simple get request using *requests*

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://www.python.org/')
print(r.text)
```

Alternative using *urllib*

```
import urllib.request
r=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/').read()
print(r)
```